# Can't change key name in HKEY_CURRENT_USER subkey (Win7)

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I have discovered weird issue today. I have a key of some application under HKEY_CURRENT_USER which I can't remove or change it's name. There is no problem with other keys. Regedit is working with administrator privilages. I checked permissions of this special key and they are no different from other applications keys. But this special one I can't touch. Moreover I have manually set privilage for Everyone with full permissions and still nothing (yes, I can add or remove permissions and I can modify values in those keys). I have checked that no instances of application is run and it's service is also stopped. ProcessExplorer in user/admin mode couldn't find any process which could interfere with the key. I don't have any antiviruses applications currently, used AVG but fully removed it few months ago. Anything more i can check to uncover such mystery?
The application is Fortinet in some old version.

Comment: Most likely the old Fortinet application is locking the key much like apps lock files in use.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click the key or the key above and access its permissions.

If the permissions on the key in question cannot be edited to allow you access, do this for the permissions on the key one level higher.

From here, you can propagate permissions downwards to restore permissions. After these are correct, you can delete the key again.

You may have to get owner for that key.

These permissions work the same as the security tab for folders.

In extreme cases, apps can lock a registry key similarly as to how one can keep a folder or file open by setting a write-lock to it. If the above fails, then this is the only way it is being blocked. Stopping the app that blocks it is the way to make it possible to delete/modify that regkey.

Comment: My current account is the owner of this key and most other keys under HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sometimes SYSTEM is the owner. I can change permissions of Fortinet key (adding or taking back permissions) without issue - I pointed it in question. And as far as I am aware any instance of Fortinet is not run. ProcessExplorer has nice feature to look for handles, and registry key name is also a start point to find application which interfere with such key.

Comment: Use MSCONFIG and boot into SAFE MODE... Try it in SAFE MODE, without Internet, and open REGEDIT and go to the Key and right click and take Ownership and add yourself as a user with full privileges. Make your changes... And then...?